# How do I give file name instead of full file path in cut in read.csv in R?

Tags: r

```
fl <- /home/somefile.csv;
x <- read.csv(pipe("cut -f3 -d',' fl"));
```

It throws an error, saying `cut: fl: No such file or directory`.

Comment: Can you rewrite for x as in above?

Comment: You could try writing the commands in R.

Comment: @Serban : A little specific direct suggestion would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `x <- read.csv(pipe(paste("cut -f3 -d',' ", fl)))` where `fl` has been defined in quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `paste` to combine the filepath string with the shell commands

```
# Create some example data
write.csv(mtcars, "somefile.csv")

# Define filepath as a character string
fl <- "somefile.csv"

# Read in third column by pasteing strings together
x <- read.csv(pipe(paste("cut -f3 -d',' ", fl)))

head(x)
#  cyl
#1   6
#2   6
#3   4
#4   6
#5   8
#6   6
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, R likes strings for many inputs:

```
setwd("/home/user/folder")  #sets your working directyory
list.files()  #lists the files in the working directory
myfilename <- "somefile.csv"  #sets the file name
x <- read.csv(myfilename)  # reads file into x
```

Comment: This is okay, but the problem is I have more than 1 columns in my file and I need to read only a particular column (3rd one in my case), hence have used pipe and cut, but then the file name is not static, hence trying to pass filename instead of full path, but not working.